# Como agregar Cabecera a un Reporte Excel con PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, excel

Necesito generar un reporte en excel con Cabecera, es decir, agregarle quien lo hizo, el departamento, la hora que descargo el excel desde la pagina. etc... etc ... ya me genera el reporte, pero no tengo idea de como agregar lo otro.

**Este es archivo que se descarga**

```
header('Content-Type:text/csv; charset=latin1');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Reporte Marcaje.xls"');



        $conn=new PDO('mssql:host=192.168.20.219; dbname=Intranet', 'adam', 'adam219');

          $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

         $confech=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM marcaje");

 ?>




<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />


    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>


        <table class="table" id="ocultarFecha">
            <tr>
            <td class="nombreNegrita">Fecha Entrada</td>
            <td class="nombreNegrita">Hora Entrada</td>
            <td class="nombreNegrita">Cédula</td>
            <td class="nombreNegrita">Nombre</td>
            <td class="nombreNegrita">Cargo</td>
            <td class="nombreNegrita">Departamento</td>
            <td class="nombreNegrita">Fecha de Revista</td>
            <td class="nombreNegrita">Hora de Revista</td>
            <td class="nombreNegrita">Encargado</td>
            <td class="nombreNegrita">Cargo</td>
            <td class="nombreNegrita">Departamento</td>
            <td class="nombreNegrita">Sucursal</td>
            </tr>

                <?php 
                     while($row=$confech->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                 ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['fechEntrada'];  ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['horaEntrada']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['cedula']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['nombre']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['cargo']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['departamento']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['fechRevista']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['horaRevista']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['usuario_sesion']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['cargo_sesion']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['departamento_sesion']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['sucursal_sesion']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>

        </table>



</body>
</html>
```

incluso, he intentado hacerlo con la libreria PHPExcel y no me sale nada.

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un ejemplo que te puede orientar usando la librería [PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet), ya que la librería PHPExcel esta deprecada.

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
$phpExcel = new Spreadsheet();

//aca seteas las propiedades
$phpExcel->getProperties()
->setCreator('Superman')
->setTitle('un titulo')
->setSubject('algo mas')
->setDescription('una descripcion');
->setLastModifiedBy("Batman")
->setKeywords("palabras clave")
->setCategory("una categoria");

//Seteas los "titulos" de las columnas
$phpExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
     ->setCellValue('A1','Fecha Entrada')
     ->setCellValue('B1','Hora Entrada')
     //todas las demas columnas
     ->setCellValue('C1','Sucursal Sesion');

//Luego podes meterle los datos de la consulta asi
$fila = 2;
while($row=$confech->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $phpExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
    ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1, $fila , $row["fechEntrada"])
    ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(2, $fila , $row["horaEntrada"])
    //todas las demas columnas
    ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(12, $fila , $row["sucursal_sesion"]);

    $fila++;
}

$writer = new Xlsx($phpExcel);
$writer->save('MiExcel.xlsx');
```